# Infinite cartesian product equals Finite Cartesian product when the index is $\{1, 2, ... , n\}$ Confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First we denote the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ by $B^A$

Definition of Finite Cartesian product:

> $\prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_{i} := \{(x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n} : x_i \in X_i \space   \forall \space   1 \leq i \leq n\} $

Definition of Infinite Cartesian product:

> $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_{i} = \{(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I} \in (\bigcup_{\beta \in I}X_\beta)^I : x_\alpha \in X_\alpha \space \forall \space \alpha \in I\}$

Now im stuck on:

> If $I$ is a set of the form $ I := \{i \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ then $\prod_{\alpha \in I} X_{i} $ is the same set as $\prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_{i}$

Heres what im stuck on,
take $z \in \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n} X_{i}$ so $z = (x_i)_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ where $x_i \in X_i \space \forall \space  i \in I$

so we have $x_i \in X_i \space \forall \space  i \in I$ now we just need to show $z \in (\bigcup_{\beta \in I}X_\beta)^I$ since then we can conclude $z \in \prod_{\alpha \in I} X_{i}$ but how do we show this? Does this just simply come from the fact $n-tuples$ are functions from $I$ to an arbitrary set $X$ (in our case $X$ is just $ (\bigcup_{\beta \in I}X_\beta)^I$)

Comment: There are different ways to define an $n$-tuple with $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ and most of the time we don't care which one is which because anything said  with one definition can be logically transcribed to another definition without telling us anything new.... & you have a typo in the def'n of Infinite Product: $X_i$ should be $X_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Yes it comes from the fact that $n$-tuples are just functions from $I = \{1, \ldots, n\} \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i$, and with that realization the two definitions are identical. The only difference between them is that the first specifies a particular index set, and the second is more careful in its set-builder notation. But the set it is building is exactly the same, given the index set.

Comment: So what would a formal proof look like? For example the other inclusion seems just as strange.